# What is the meaning of 'ER_SELECT_REDUCED' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I was execute the following SQL:

```
# id is PRIMARY, int type
EXPLAIN SELECT game_match_id FROM t1
     WHERE id = (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1)));

show warnings;
```

Output:

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Note | 1249 | Select 2 was reduced during optimization |
| Note | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `wave`.`t1`.`game_match_id` AS `game_match_id` from `wave`.`t1` where (`wave`.`t1`.`id` = ceiling((rand() * (/* select#3 */ select max(`wave`.`t1`.`id`) from `wave`.`t1`)))) |

I search the code 1249, I found:

> ER_SELECT_REDUCED: Select %u was reduced during optimization

I didn't understand that.  Any example to understand it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the optimizer was able to reduce a `SELECT` query to a constant during optimization. Since there's an index on `t1.id`, `SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1` can be determined by the optimizer, and that subquery is replaced by its value.

This is explained in the O'Reilly book [High Performance MySQL](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html)

> When MySQL detects that an expression can be reduced to a constant, it will do so during optimization. For example, a user-defined variable can be converted to a constant if it’s not changed in the query. Arithmetic expressions are another example.
>
> Perhaps surprisingly, even something you might consider to be a query can be reduced to a constant during the optimization phase. One example is a MIN() on an index. This can even be extended to a constant lookup on a primary key or unique index. If a WHERE clause applies a constant condition to such an index, the optimizer knows MySQL can look up the value at the beginning of the query. It will then treat the value as a constant in the rest of the query.

So the `(SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT ...))` can also be reduced, since it can generate the random number during optimization and multiply this by `MAX(id)` from the index.

Comment: what is the %u represented? why 2 in the above example?

Comment: It's replaced with the number of the SELECT query or subquery. I think there should be a `select#2`, but it's not showing up in the message. It looks like the optimizer also converted it into a simple expression, so it's `ceiling(...)`

Answer (score 0):

(Instead of dwelling on the strange error message, I will help you get the query you wanted.)

Suggest you rephrase it thus:

```
SELECT game_match_id
    FROM t1 AS a
    JOIN ( SELECT CEIL(RAND() * MAX(id)) AS rid
              FROM t1
         ) AS b
      ON a.id = b.rid;
```

Note:  This will sometimes fail if there are gaps in `id`.  Here's a longer discussion of getting "a random row":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random